# Creating a deck of cards and shuffling them

Tags: java

I have been stuck on this for sometime now, the objective is to create an array to hold the cards in, once I do create the array print them out the only card that is printing is king of hearts. Why is it not iterating?

```
public class Card
{
    // Card suits (provided for your convenience - use is optional)
    public static final int SPADES   = 0;
    public static final int HEARTS   = 1;
    public static final int CLUBS    = 2;
    public static final int DIAMONDS = 3;

    // Card faces (provided for your convenience - use is optional)
    public static final int ACE      = 1;
    public static final int TWO      = 2;
    public static final int THREE    = 3;
    public static final int FOUR     = 4;
    public static final int FIVE     = 5;
    public static final int SIX      = 6;
    public static final int SEVEN    = 7;
    public static final int EIGHT    = 8;
    public static final int NINE     = 9;
    public static final int TEN      = 10;
    public static final int JACK     = 11;
    public static final int QUEEN    = 12;
    public static final int KING     = 13;




    // define fields here
    private static int suit;
    private static int val;
    private String[] suits = {"Clubs", "Spades", "Diamonds", "Hearts"};
    private String[] vals = {"Ace","2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", 
            "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King" };

    // This constructor builds a card with the given suit and face, turned face down.
    public Card(int suit, int val)
    {

        this.val = val;
        this.suit = suit;

    }

    public @Override String toString()
    {
        return vals[val] + " Of " + suits[suit];
    }

    // This method retrieves the suit (spades, hearts, etc.) of this card.
    public int getSuit()
    {

        return this.suit;

    }

    // This method retrieves the face (ace through king) of this card.
    public int getFace()
    {
//      return this.val;

        switch(val)
        {
        case 0 : return 1;
        case 1 : return 2;
        case 2 : return 3;
        case 3 : return 4;
        case 5 : return 6;
        case 6 : return 7;
        case 7 : return 8;
        case 8 : return 9;
        case 9 : return 10;
        case 10 : return 10;
        case 12 : return 10;
        default : return 0;
        }
    }








}`


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
// This class represents the deck of cards from which cards are dealt to players.
public class Deck
{
    //array
    public static Card[] cards; 
//  private static ArrayList<Card> cards;

    int i;
    int counter;


    // This constructor builds a deck of 52 cards.
    Deck()
    {
        i = 51;
        //array implementation 
        cards = new Card[52];
        int x = 0;


        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < 13;j++)
            {

                //Array implementation 
                cards[x] = new Card(i,j);
                x++;
            }
        }


    }




    // This method takes the top card off the deck and returns it.
    public Card deal()
    {

        //Array implementation 
        int index = 0;
        Card temp = cards[index];

        return temp;

    }


    // this method returns true if there are no more cards to deal, false otherwise
    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        if(cards.length == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    //this method puts the deck int some random order
//  public void shuffle()
//  {
//      for(int i = 51; i > 0; i--)
//      {
//          int rand = (int) (Math.random() * (i+1));
//          Card temp = this.cards[i];
//          this.cards[i] = cards[rand];
//          cards[rand] = temp;
//      }
//  
//  }


}


public class BlackJack extends Deck
{
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        System.out.println("Ready to play a game of BlackJack?");

        Deck deck = new Deck();
        for(int i = 0; i < cards.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(cards[i]);
        }
```

Comment: The Oracle Java tutorials have a deck of cards example that would be useful for you.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/QandE/creating-answers.html

Answer (score 5):

Problem is caused by the following:

```
// define fields here
private static int suit;
private static int val;
```

because they are static, all Card instances share these, so they will all have the last value they were set to.  Remove the static.

Comment: Thank you, I cant believe I didn't notice that haha.

Answer (score 1):

To give you a little hint how you might make the code even easier to read/maintain:

- use enums instead of constants. You can give them constructors/member variables just like classes
- use for-each-loops, it's way easier to read and prevents the usual off-by-1 problems
- type 'static' BEFORE all other modifiers and keep all static variables and members separate from any non-static content. this way you can never mix them up by accident

Bad / unusual sides of this code are:

- I use static nested enums and classes. Usually each of those should go into its own file and be non-static
- I like to prefix my variables according to their scope so I cannot mess em up: pXxx for Parameter, sXxx for static variables, mXxxx for members, no prefix for method variables

```
public class CardGame {
```

`static public enum SuitType {
        SPADES, HEARTS, CLUBS, DIAMONDS
    }

    static public enum FaceType {
        ACE("Ace", 1), //
        TWO("2", 2), //
        THREE("3", 3), //
        FOUR("4", 4), //
        FIVE("5", 5), //
        SIX("6", 6), //
        SEVEN("7", 7), //
        EIGHT("8", 8), //
        NINE("9", 9), //
        TEN("10", 10), //
        JACK("Jack", 11), //
        QUEEN("Queen", 12), //
        KING("King", 13), //
        ;

        private final String    mName;
        private final int       mValue;

        private FaceType(final String pName, final int pValue) {
            mName = pName;
            mValue = pValue;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return mName;
        }
        public int getValue() {
            return mValue;
        }
        public int getValue_alternative() {
            return ordinal() + 1; // ordinal is the index of the enum, starting at ace=0 ... king=12
            // sorting and comparing of suits could also be done by .ordinal() if need be
        }
    }

    static public class Card {
        private final SuitType  mSuit;
        private final FaceType  mFace;

        public Card(final SuitType pSuit, final FaceType pFace) {
            mSuit = pSuit;
            mFace = pFace;
        }

        public SuitType getSuit() {
            return mSuit;
        }
        public FaceType getFace() {
            return mFace;
        }
        @Override public String toString() {
            return mFace.getName() + " of " + mSuit + " - " + mFace.getValue() + (mFace.getValue() > 1 ? " points" : " point");
        }
    }

    static public class Deck {

        private final ArrayList<Card>   mCards;

        public Deck() {
            mCards = createFullDeck();
        }

        private ArrayList<Card> createFullDeck() { // can also be static as it dowes not use member cariables => potential factory method
            final ArrayList<Card> ret = new ArrayList<>();
            for (final SuitType suit : SuitType.values()) {
                for (final FaceType face : FaceType.values()) {
                    final Card c = new Card(suit, face);
                    ret.add(c);
                }
            }
            return ret;
        }

        public void shuffleRandomly() {
            final ArrayList<Card> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
            tempList.addAll(mCards);
            mCards.clear();
            while (tempList.size() > 0) {
                final int index = (int) (Math.random() * tempList.size());
                final Card card = tempList.remove(index);
                mCards.add(card);
            }
        }

        public void print() {
            System.out.println(" - - - DECK BEGINS - - - ");
            int counter = 0;
            for (final Card c : mCards) {
                System.out.println("\t" + c);
                ++counter;
            }
            System.out.println("> Printed " + counter + " cards.");
            System.out.println(" - - - DECK ENDS - - - ");
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Deck d = new Deck();
        d.print();
        d.shuffleRandomly();
        d.print();
    }

}`